# JENKINS Tortoise SVN link - Unable to connect to repository

Tags: python, jenkins, svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to link JENKINS and tortoise SVN but I am unable to. I have tried the below methods:

1. Create batch file for an SVN checkout - Works fine
2. Call the same batch file from Jenkins as a Batch command step in Jenkins - Does not work
3. Tried writing a python script and tried a subprocess.call() with svn checkout - Does not work.

I get the below error when I try with Jenkins -
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL
svn: E215004: No more credentials or we tried too many times
Authentication failed.

Answer (score 1):

Finally was able to solve it. Clear the cache present for SVN credentials and use the --username --password for the SVN command.